# Go HTTP Response to a File and Json

Tags: rest, go

I'm trying to create an upload REST API with Go.

and I want to return how many data that success and failure. and return the failed data to CSV or XLS file.

but I don't know how to return with two different things like this.

is it possible to return JSON and file at the same time? if possible, how?

Comment: You can’t respond with both a file and JSON (I mean technically it’s possible, but would require a custom content-type and response parser on the client). The typical approach to this is to have your API endpoint respond with JSON describing the output that also includes a URL to download the CSV from. The endpoint at that URL would then respond with the file upon request.

Comment: Respond with with a [multipart body](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Writer) containing the JSON document and CSV file.